# Generate method stub in Visual Studio 2010 always uses string instead of String

Tags: visual-studio-2010, methods, stub

How can I change that generating a method stub generates me a big "String" type instead of the small "string" ?

Comment: `string` is c# syntactic sugar for `String` - they compile to the same CIL. Why is this an issue?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: Because syntax coloring for class names is prettier than the keywords one.

Comment: @Johann - seeing as you can't change the style in Visual Studio. Oh, wait

Comment: @Oskar because its our company coding guideline style to use String instead of string and Double instead of double... using the generate method stub became a mess...

Comment: @msfanboy I can't really see the benefit of having such guidelines when they are the same.

Comment: @Oskar tell that the team I am in...

Comment: @msfanboy I would if I were there :D

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a macro and post process the result (that is, the generated stub).
Use `DTE.ExecuteCommand("EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Generate.GenerateMethodStub")` to activate the tool.

Quite ugly, but it doesn't seem that visual studio externalize any interface to it...

HTH